# How to replace � with & in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have an external window app calling a PERL script with a string that contains �. I'm trying to detect each such instance and replace it with a &.

I tried using all of these but nothing works:

```
$line =~ s/\uFFFD/&/g;
$line =~ s/&#65533/&/g;
$line =~ s/\x{fffd}/&/g;
$line =~ s/\xfffd/&/g;
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; warn(Dumper($str)); }`

Comment: If you had character FFFD, the third would have worked.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito, That character is used to represent something invalid. Putting something invalid in your source code is a poor choice.

Comment: @ikegami , I understand that but I can't change anything in the windows app.

Comment: I used the Data::Dumper and as part of the string I get this \\302\\201. SO if I apply "s/\x81/&/g" I get "�&". How do I get rid of that � or \\302?

Comment: I guess I answered my own question. s/\x81/&/g | s/\302//g

Answer (score 0):

As ikegami pointed out in their comment, the third solution (`$line =~ s/\x{fffd}/&/g;`) is the correct one. If it does not work, one of your assumptions has to be wrong. Two possibilities come to my mind:

- Your input does not contain an actual [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm). It may be the case that your editor renders another sequence of bytes in the same way. You can check it by running `hexdump -c`. If your input is encoded in UTF-8 (mind the difference between UTF8 and Unicode), you should see the following sequence: `357 277 275`.
- You did not inform perl about the input text encoding. Perl assumes it is a one-byte encoding and thus a regex containing a multibyte character will never match. Please compare the following:

  > echo '�' | perl -pe 's/\x{fffd}/&/'
  >
  > �
  >
  > echo '�' | perl -CS -pe 's/\x{fffd}/&/'
  >
  > &